# JavaScript async callback and scope

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, scope

Consider the following example:

```
var cb = function (t) {
    console.log('callback -->' + t);
};

for(var i = 0; i<3; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    setTimeout(function(){
        cb(i);
    },1000);
}
```

[Working example at jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jE8Ra/)

The output of this code snippet is:

```
0
1
2
callback ---> 3
callback ---> 3
callback ---> 3
```

Everything works as expected, for loop puts 3 callback calls into the event loop. By the end of the for loop i == 3 and when the callbacks get executed all of them print 3 because they contain the link to the i which is 3.
How could this snippet be improved so when the callback gets executed it uses the actual value which was passed to it.

The output should be:

```
callback ---> 1
callback ---> 2
callback ---> 3
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Create a closure](http://jsfiddle.net/jE8Ra/1/) so that the `setTimeout` handler will refer to the closure's local variable (which in this case, we also named `i`), not the `i` from the loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    (function (i) {
        console.log(i);
        setTimeout(function () {
            cb(i);
        }, 1000);
    }(i));
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You could try ***[.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)***:

```
for(var i = 0; i<3; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    setTimeout(cb.bind(null, i),1000);
}
```

***[The demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/jE8Ra/2/)***

The traditional way to handle this is to create a closure:

```
for(var i = 0; i<3; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    setTimeout((function(i){return function(){cb(i)}}(i)),1000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info on .bind I'll ponder over the documentation about it. Bind is ES5 only so I can't use it yet. Your closure solution works fine however Joseph posted similar solution first so I'm afraid I'll choose his answer. Nevertheless, thanks for sharing your knowledge !

Answer (score 3):

A frequent question.
Let's try to use some features of future of JS. I mean **let**.
It creates local scope variable and you don't need to use a closure or another trick.
But now it works only in FF (i'm using 20.0.1)

```
for(var i = 0; i<3; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    let a = i;
    setTimeout(function(){               
        cb(a);
    },1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I will just use `setTimeout()` in your cb's functoin

```
var cb = function (t) {
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('callback -->' + t);
  },1000);
};


for(var i = 0; i<3; i++) {
    console.log(i);
        cb(i);
}
```

Comment: Nice, but there's no need for `cb` to not be defined inline ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately this can't be done. Callback is called by the async function but it doesn't contain one itself.